# Location markers in sub sampling scale image view

Tags: android, dictionary, imageview

I am using Dave Morrissey's sub sampling scale Image View to display a high resolution map image. I want to add location markers at predefined coordinates on the map such that even when the image is zoomed or panned around, the markers stay put at the specified coordinates. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extend the SubsamplingScaleImageView and override its onDraw() method

```
public class MapView extends SubsamplingScaleImageView {

    private PointF sPin;

    ArrayList<MapPin> mapPins;
    ArrayList<DrawnPin> drawnPins;
    Context context;
    String tag = getClass().getSimpleName();

    public MapView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
        this.context = context;
    }

    public MapView(Context context, AttributeSet attr) {
        super(context, attr);
        this.context = context;
        initialise();
    }

    public void setPins(ArrayList<MapPin> mapPins)
    {
        this.mapPins = mapPins;
        initialise();
        invalidate();
    }


    public PointF getPin() {
        return sPin;
    }

    private void initialise() {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        // Don't draw pin before image is ready so it doesn't move around during setup.
        if (!isReady()) {
            return;
        }

        drawnPins = new ArrayList<>();

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi;


        for(int i=0;i<mapPins.size();i++)
        {
            MapPin mPin = mapPins.get(i);
            Bitmap bmpPin = Utils.getBitmapFromAsset(context, mPin.getPinImgSrc());

            float w = (density/420f) * bmpPin.getWidth();
            float h = (density/420f) * bmpPin.getHeight();
            bmpPin = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmpPin, (int)w, (int)h, true);

            PointF vPin = sourceToViewCoord(mPin.getPoint());
            //in my case value of point are at center point of pin image, so we need to adjust it here

            float vX = vPin.x - (bmpPin.getWidth()/2);
            float vY = vPin.y - (bmpPin.getHeight()/2);

            canvas.drawBitmap(bmpPin, vX, vY, paint);
        //add added pin to an Array list to get touched pin
            DrawnPin dPin = new DrawnPin();
            dPin.setStartX(mPin.getX()-w/2);
            dPin.setEndX(mPin.getX()+w/2);
            dPin.setStartY(mPin.getY()-h/2);
            dPin.setEndY(mPin.getY()+h/2);
            dPin.setId(mPin.getId());
            drawnPins.add(dPin);
        }

    }

    public int getPinIdByPoint(PointF point)
    {

        for(int i=drawnPins.size()-1;i>=0;i--)
        {
            DrawnPin dPin = drawnPins.get(i);
            if(point.x >= dPin.getStartX() && point.x<=dPin.getEndX())
            {
                if(point.y >= dPin.getStartY() && point.y<=dPin.getEndY())
                {
                    return dPin.getId();
                }
            }
        }
        return -1; //negative no means no pin selected
    }

    class DrawnPin
    {
        float startX,startY,endX,endY;
        int id;

        public DrawnPin(float startX, float startY, float endX, float endY, int id)
        {
            this.startX = startX;
            this.startY = startY;
            this.endX = endX;
            this.endY = endY;
            this.id = id;
        }
    public DrawnPin()
    {
        //empty
    }
        public float getStartX()
        {
            return startX;
        }

        public void setStartX(float startX)
        {
            this.startX = startX;
        }

        public float getStartY()
        {
            return startY;
        }

        public void setStartY(float startY)
        {
            this.startY = startY;
        }

        public float getEndX()
        {
            return endX;
        }

        public void setEndX(float endX)
        {
            this.endX = endX;
        }

        public float getEndY()
        {
            return endY;
        }

        public void setEndY(float endY)
        {
            this.endY = endY;
        }

        public int getId()
        {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(int id)
        {
            this.id = id;
        }



    }
```

Comment: can you please share the MapPin class also? I copied your code and this class is missing. Thank you!